# Engine jolting and struggle starting

Tags: engine, starting, vw

I drive a 2002 VW Polo automatic, and in the last few days it's really been struggling to start when it's cold, and then this morning the car would jolt on acceleration every now and again, when the revs got above 3000 or so, suddenly lurching forward a little, then continuing smoothly. Does anyone know, are these problems likely to be related, and is it something I could fix myself?

(The car also had the battery replaced about six months ago, and the alternator about three months ago, and just passed its Warrant of Fitness with no issues last month, and no lights are coming on the dashboard.)

[image: Under the bonnet]

Comment: Is this vehicle a carburetor version?  How many cc's is your engine?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't actually know if it's a carburettor or not, but it's 1400cc. I've attached a picture if this helps, thanks

Comment: It's a 2002 Volkswagen, they don't make carbureted cars since the 90s.

Comment: Is it powered by petrol or diesel fuel?

Comment: It's a petrol powered car.

Comment: This could be an issue with your fuel pump or your injectors or a lot of other things. There are too many possibilities. From a simplistic point of view, it sounds like your engine is starving. If you could record a video of the situation, it would be great. Does your engine lose power gradually before the lurch?

Comment: I actually can't record a video, this happened about ten days ago now, several times over two drives, and since that morning hasn't happened since. I guess that's a good thing, but it doesn't exactly fill me with confidence. I am reasonably confident the engine didn't lose power before the lurches, but not sure.